How to convert Firestore timestamp to ISO 8601 in python?
I am writing a firebase cloud function in python to read data from firestore database and update it into the firebase realtime database, however I am facing an issue with converting the firestore datetime to ISO 8601 format so i can store the date in a JSON format.
I believe there exists a library to do this in javascript but not in python.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
import datetime
from google.cloud import firestore

def serialize_datetime(dt):
    """ Convert Firestore Timestamp or Python datetime to ISO 8601 string. """
    if isinstance(dt, firestore.Timestamp):
        return dt.to_pydatetime().isoformat()
    elif isinstance(dt, datetime.datetime):
        return dt.isoformat()
    return dt

'order_datetime': serialize_datetime(order_data.get('orderDate')),
'expiry_datetime': serialize_datetime(order_data.get('deliveryDate')),

